# Onclick change color + text using a tag

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script language="javascript">

    function changecolor (i)
    {
        if(document.getElementById)
            document.getElementById(i).color = "green";
        else if(document.all)
            document.all[i].color = "red";

        return false;
    }

</script>



<h1>Edit Status: 
    <a href="#" onClick="return changecolor('item1')" class="a">
        <font style="color: #f00;">
            <font id=item1>Disabled</font>
    </a>
</h1><br></font>
```

I have the above text color changer, now i want to create disable in red color and when you click it the text change and the color becomes green, if you click again it will return..

Then how can i do that? that code working only when i click once and it not change the text..

Thanks to all of you guys!

Comment: mixing css with `<font>` tags is never a good idea. Your html is highly broken/invalid as well, so no wonder you're having trouble.

Comment: I edited this, can some of you review it?

Comment: As Marc says, your HTML is invalid... in particular you are not closing the tags in the reverse order that they were created. For example `<h1><b></b></h1>` is valid but `<h1><b></h1></b>` is not

Comment: I really do not think there is a browser that does not support the `document.getElementById`. What are you trying to achive here, exactly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `<font>` HTML tag, what is not recommended. You should use CSS for style your HTML tags.

You can read about CSS here: [W3schools - CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/)

I think this HTML will be good for you:

```
<h1>Edit Status: 
    <a href="#" onClick="return changecolor(this)" style="color: red;">Disabled</a>
</h1>
```

Use this script to change the text and the color:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function changecolor(element){
    if (element.innerHTML == "Disabled"){
        element.innerHTML = "Enabled";
        element.style.color = "green";
    } else {
        element.innerHTML = "Disabled";
        element.style.color = "red";
    }
    return false;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at your nesting of HTML elements:

```
<h1>Edit Status: 
    <a href="#" onClick="return changecolor('item1')" class="a">
        <font style="color: #f00;">
            <font id=item1>Disabled</font>
        </a>   <----- bad
    </h1>      <----- bad
    <br>
</font>        <----- bad
```

I'd suggest:

1. Remove all `<font>` tags, as this isn't 1997. :)  Use CSS
2. Fix the nesting of your elements
3. Update your question with your fixed code

Answer (score 0):

Your check is very strange. I can't see a scenario where `document.getelementById` will not be available to you.

You are wanting something more like:

```
function changecolor (controlID)
{
    var obj = document.getElementById(controlID);

    //switch color and change text conditionally:
    if(obj.color === "green"){
        obj.color = "red";
        obj.innerText = "Disabled";
    } else {
        obj.color = "green";
        obj.innerText = "Enabled";
    }
}
```

But aside from that you have malformed HTML, so you should really look to correct that as well.

Comment: Very old IE required the check. Certainly not needed today.

Comment: Alright, so i did remove the font and  James answer were really helpful about colors, but what about text change?

Comment: You'll be wanting the innerText property

Comment: @JamesWiseman: The standards version is `.textContent`, but IE8 and lower doesn't support it. Usually I create a variable: `var text = ('textContent' in document) ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';`, Then use the variable to get/set text `obj[text] = "foobar";`

Comment: @user1689607 More useful info. Cheers

Comment: Well, i not JS / AJAX editor, only php, html, sql, css, xml.. then how exactly can i do that?
Edit:
I did read your post user1689607 but i cannot understand it.